# How to export optimization model in ojalgo

Tags: optimization, export, ojalgo

I build up a optimization model in ojalgo (ExpressionsBasedModel). Is there a way to export it to check the model? So far I am only able to export the lower and upper limits of variables and constraints but I am not able to export the variable's coefficients of constraints. I checked the available functions but I coudn't find an appropriate one. Only importing an MPS file I could find. Has someone a hint how to export the model without using an extra framework/external libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to generate/export an MPS file using ojAlgo.

If you want to verify solver results with some 3:d party solver, you can do that. I believe the community (free) version of cplex allows up to 1000 variables and constraints.

https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo-extensions/tree/master/ojAlgo-cplex

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's a pity that there is no native export capability. 
Your suggestion is what I am doing more or less now using an external solver to export the model data. However, I have had to change the package source code and I thought I could avoid it.

Comment: By the way, the cplex extension has an error in file SolverCPLEX.java in line 254. Limited fixed variables are not contained in the myIloCplex object. This has to be checked here.

Comment: If you think you found a bug (or made some improvements) then open an issue or pull request at GitHub. https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo-extensions/issues

Comment: I opened an issue as I have almost no understanding of the whole library.